# Angular2 AOT compiler keeps asking for Name

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

Is there a reason (that I can fix) why when I do:

`ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json`

That in response, it asks for:

`Name:`

It seems that the `ngc` simply ignores my `tsconfig.aot.json`.

What could be the reason for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

NPM is confused between the Component generator package called as **ngc**, So uninstall it, then AOT build will go on smooth

```
npm uninstall ngc -g
```

then in your **package.json** make an entry

```
 "scripts": {
    "ngc": "node_modules/.bin/ngc -p ./tsconfig-aot.json",
    "start": "npm run ngc && webpack-dev-server --inline --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --port 3000",
    "webpack": "npm run ngc && webpack --config config/webpack.dev.js",
```

Comment: It worked for me, there was a collision between angular-component-generator and the compiler, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check your package.json , remove the any 'ngc' module references.
2. Clean your node_modules folder
3. Re-install the required angular-cli modules

Above three steps should solve the issue.

Comment: I had this issue, too. At some point I must have installed the `ngc` package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngc which is an angular component generator that asks for a name. npm removing it allowed the Angular compiler `ngc` bin to be executed instead of that one.